# Why does my code keep renaming my file "Playlist"?

Tags: python, pygame, file-copying

I'm making a music player with python and I've added "add song to playlist" feature where it will open the explorer and a user can select a music file which it will then copy that file into a differnt directory called Playlist.

```
os.chdir("./playlist")
print(os.getcwd)
songlist = os.listdir()
playlistloc = "./playlist"

def browse_file():
    global filename_path
    filename_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(filename_path)
    add_to_playlist(filename_path)

def add_to_playlist(filename):
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    shutil.copyfile(filename_path, playlistloc)
```

I have no idea why it keeps calling it playtlist but it does play that song.
Please help and generally have no idea why it's doing it that way, is it something to do with shutil?

Comment: It calls it `playlist` because you tell it to! That’s what the last line in `add_to_playlist` does.

Comment: it doesnt say re name, that's justa trigger for it to start the next event, @KonradRudolph

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile): *dst must be the complete target file name*. That means, full path including the filename.

Comment: Ok but what do i change? Do i have to make a rename command?

Comment: ??? I don't understand what you mean, the paths are there? @sal

Comment: For example, if your song is "Song-1.mp3", then your `dst` should be like `./playlist/Song-1.mp3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a misunderstanding on how `shutil.copyfile` works. From documentation, the `dst` parameter should be the *complete target file name*. This means that folder path *and* filename should be used.

In other words, the way this works is **NOT** like this:

```
shutil.copyfile("./some/location/with/song1.mp3", "./destination/location")
```

but rather:

```
shutil.copyfile("./some/location/with/song1.mp3", "./destination/location/song1.mp3")
```

So here is an example, I changed some variable names to make them more explicit in the `add_to_playlist` function:

```
os.chdir("./playlist")
print(os.getcwd)
songlist = os.listdir()
playlistloc = "./playlist"

def browse_file():
    global filename_path
    filename_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(filename_path)
    add_to_playlist(filename_path)

def add_to_playlist(src_filename_path):
    src_filename = os.path.basename(src_filename_path)  # get the filename alone
    dst_filename_path = os.path.join(playlistloc, src_filename)  # build the destination full path: concat the filename to the destination location
    shutil.copyfile(src_filename_path, dst_filename_path)  # do the copy
```

Comment: Ohh ok I understand now but on the last line `shutil.copyfile(src_filename_path, dst_filename_path)` your copying it even tho that destination doesnt exist. So it throws an error @sal

Comment: ok, so i chnaged the playlistloc to `playlistloc ="C:/Users/mystik/Documents/MusicPlayer/playlist` so the fall path and that works, it won't let me do `playlistloc = "./playlist"` though. If I didnt use the full path it throws an error. I think it's because of the /.

Comment: Fantastic, glad it helped.